# Can I re-propose a site in Area 51 after it was deleted for not meeting the 3-day minimum requirements?

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

I decided to make a proposal, which was going fine and had many questions, but it got deleted because it only had three followers.

My question is: can I add it back in hopes of it getting more active?

Comment: I'll leave a comment as I'm not actually confident in this enough to post an answer, but: sure, why not? However, if you only got 3 followers the first time, you should change something in order to increase its following the second time.  It might be scope, it might be example questions, it might be external marketing .... but if you do the same thing, you should realistically expect similar results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're sure you can get the required followers, yes, you can.

Keep in mind that Area 51 *does not* have the built-in audience for you to get your proposal through; it's *up to you* to actively promote your proposal and get people to sign on. The 3-day, 5-follower requirement was implemented as a compromise to those who requested that users should be required to sign on those followers *at the same time* as proposing; effectively it's the same thing, but you get a 3-day grace period to do so.

Note that it's even better if you obtain a large enough community of people interested in a site *before* proposing, and then propose your site as the *last* stage in the overall process of forming a site. Many of the recent proposals that very quickly gained followers in a matter of days were done this way.

Do note that if you keep re-proposing the same site *again and again* after it keeps getting deleted for not meeting the 3-day requirements, it may cause you to get suspended from the site, as it's overall disruptive at that stage.