# Renewing a closed beta on Area 51

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

Is it possible to bring back a proposal for a site that was closed a few years ago due to lack of traffic?

The site was very close to fulfilling all the requirements. The only problem was that it had an average of 4.9 questions per day. Now I think there is more demand for the topic and a lot more people will be interested.

So, can I propose that site?

BTW I am talking about [Startup Business](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business).

Comment: That is sometimes done. IIRC it worked once but there also have been proposals where SE said: Don't try this again. Maybe check on the Area 51 discussion site for more guidance / examples on this.

Comment: @rene What's IIRC?

Comment: @AdityaJain [If I Remember Correctly](https://www.dictionary.com/e/acronyms/iirc/)

Comment: @arulkumar I thought it was the name of some stack exchange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Comment: @RobertColumbia I don't think so. Those two questions are quite different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I re-propose a site in Area 51 after it was deleted for not meeting the 3-day minimum requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317235/can-i-re-propose-a-site-in-area-51-after-it-was-deleted-for-not-meeting-the-3-da)

Comment: @Rob Not a duplicate. That question is for the case where the proposal was closed during the Definition phase (specifically for not meeting the initial requirements); this is for the case where the proposal resulted in a beta site launch but was subsequently shut down.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog Does the additional dupe link provide more **relevant** information in the *banner* that is created when this is closed for ***any*** dupe, and thus benefit everyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that might work.

[Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) is one of the revived proposals @rene might be thinking; the original seems to have failed because of a wrong scope (or entire lack thereof); see [How can we make this literature proposal succeed when other literature proposals have failed](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22392/151554) for more information. (I didn't join Stack Exchange until much later and don't know about the details.) Right now, it's not a stellar site, with only [1.8 questions per day](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature), but it's alive.

I wouldn't call 4.9 questions per day problematic; [almost half of the sites are at or under that level](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). It's nowhere near the level required to graduate (10 questions per day) but I wouldn't worry about that right now; the way Stack Exchange treats beta sites is [currently a subject of discussion anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322781/writing-se-clamours-for-graduation).

Comment: I think 4.9 questions per day during private beta might cause the site to not reach the public beta, so it is crucial in that early stage.

Comment: The last beta had [7/day](https://data.stackexchange.com/or/query/1019088/questions-per-week) in the first two weeks. 4.9 is not that far off.

Comment: The questions per day wasn't great, and it decreased over time; but focused **quality** questions aren't easy to come up with for that site. It was probably the [explosive followers and commitment charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDDrI.png) along with a hunch or gut instinct that said: "Give it a chance.". We self-moderated quite well and didn't give RobC a bunch of headaches. People were able to advance enough to do the review queues. While it's been a slow start, and (probably) most people don't know what OR even is, we are growing very slowly and appear that we will eventually succeed.